# Добавление данных в две таблицы

Tags: c++, sql, access

Есть БД Acces. В ней две таблицы.

[image]

Есть форма с++ через которую добавляются данные.

[image]

Данные в столбцы id_CvetForms,id_StilForms,id_RazmerForms таблицы Nastroiki пользователю не нужно вводить. Добавляемая информация присвоена переменным (Стандартные настройки формы).

Вопрос в следующем.
Как сделать добавление, чтобы при нажатии на кнопку введенные пользователем данные добавились в обе таблицы и значение столбца Id_Nastroiki таблицы Nastroiki добавлялся в таблицу Polzovateli в столбец id_Nastroiki. Помогите написать запрос в ADOQuery и потом его при нажатии на кнопку программно реализовать. Я не знаю SQL.

Зачем все это мне надо? Добавление в одну таблицу всех данных я смогу осуществить. Но мне захотелось хранить данные о пользователе в одной таблице а его настройки приложения в другой.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Делаешь два запроса, первым добавляешь настройки, получаешь id добавленной записи, вторым обновляешь id_nastroiky в таблице пользователей. 
Логика элементарная, учи sql если собираешься работать с базами данных или постоянно будут возникать подобные вопросы. И совет, называй все поля и таблицы не транслитом, а английскими словами, выглядит ужасно.

Comment: Ну первый я знаю как написать и то выбьет ошибку потому что таблицы связные. А вот как второй написать ? Как обновить ? И выходит во второй нужно вписать что то для добавления данных в Polzovateli.

Comment: Значит нужно либо убрать связь, либо поменять на on update cascade. На счет того как сделать обновление подсказать не могу, не знаю ADOquery.

Answer (score -1):

В ADOQuery3 прописал `Select @@Identity`. Затем активировал компонент.
В программе написал следующее

```
ADOQuery3->SQL->Clear();

Edit1->Text = ADOQuery3->SQL->Add("SELECT max(id_Nastroiki) FROM Nastroiki");

ADOQuery3->Active=True;
```

**Выводит   0.**

Comment: Если есть, что добавить к вопросу - обновляй вопрос. Не надо плодить ответы к вопросу, которые не являются ответами, а лишь дополнениями к вопросу.